# Arrayformula to get closest non-numeric value above

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have Column A with mixed data types (numbers and strings) and in Column B I want for each numbers in Column A to display the string that is the closest above. Example:

```
Title|
1|Title
2|Title
Next title|
3|Next title
etc.
```

I was able to do it with a formula per row (here in B5 for instance):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER($A5),INDEX($A:$A,MAX(NOT(ISNUMBER($A$1:$A5))*(ROW($A$1:$A5))),1),"")
```

But as I have thousands of lines I'm looking for an `=ARRAYFORMULA()` solution, if possible.

Example to play with:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VQpXs8-yPcLwLTxqWJnHFW-xlOsdmwxQHgxbQpDgU1k/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is to use `vlookup()` with `is_sorted` set to `true`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    proper( 
      regexextract( 
        vlookup( 
          if( isnumber(A2:A), text(row(A2:A), "000000") & "µ" & A2:A, iferror(1/0) ), 
          if( istext(A2:A), text(row(A2:A), "000000") & "µ" & A2:A, iferror(1/0) ), 
          1, 
          true 
        ), 
        "µ(.+)" 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

The `true` will make `vlookup()` find the first non-blank value that is equal to *or less than* the key, **provided** that the key column in the data range is sorted. The `if()` bits make sure that search keys only appear in rows where column `A` contains a *number*, and that the data range only contains suitable keys in rows where column `A` contains *text*.

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VQpXs8-yPcLwLTxqWJnHFW-xlOsdmwxQHgxbQpDgU1k/edit#gid=896791770) sheet in your sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks @doubleunary I didn't expect going this way and I have to admit I still don't really understand how this formula works. If it's possible to detail the steps/process in your answer, this would be of great help for similar situation I  (and others) might face in the future

Comment: Edited the answer to include a short explanation.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'll try to replicate the idea on other data